# I want to extract the content of <span> tag from this received JSON Response. How to do that?

Tags: android, html, json, retrofit, android-volley

This is the response i got. I want to extract the `<span>` tag from `price_html`

````
        "id": 2320,
        "name": "Lakme Sun Expert Sunscreen (spf-50) 50ml",
        "slug": "lakme-sun-expert-sunscreen-spf-50-50ml",
        "permalink": "https://www.utkalmerchandise.com/product/lakme-sun-expert-sunscreen-spf-50-50ml/",
        "date_created": "2020-08-01T05:49:57",
        "date_created_gmt": "2020-08-01T05:49:57",
        "date_modified": "2020-08-01T05:49:57",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2020-08-01T05:49:57",
        "type": "variable",
        "status": "publish",
        "featured": false,
        "catalog_visibility": "visible",
        "description": "",
        "short_description": "",
        "sku": "",
        "price": "95",
        "regular_price": "",
        "sale_price": "",
        "date_on_sale_from": null,
        "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
        "date_on_sale_to": null,
        "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
        "price_html": "<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#8377;</span>95.00</span> &ndash; <span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#8377;</span>219.00</span>",```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have it as a string you can use

```
string.indexOf("<span class="...">")
```

which will return the index of the first char in the search string. Then you add the length of the search string to that index and save to *index*. Then you can do `string.indexOf("</", index)` to get the end of the content. And with `string.subString(indexStart, indexEnd)` you get the content.

**Edit:** If you can't get it to work with that take a look at the *org.json* package which is really useful when working with java and json.

Answer (score 0):

just reference the object

```js
var myObj={"id": 2320,
        "name": "Lakme Sun Expert Sunscreen (spf-50) 50ml",
        "slug": "lakme-sun-expert-sunscreen-spf-50-50ml",
        "permalink": "https://www.utkalmerchandise.com/product/lakme-sun-expert-sunscreen-spf-50-50ml/",
        "date_created": "2020-08-01T05:49:57",
        "date_created_gmt": "2020-08-01T05:49:57",
        "date_modified": "2020-08-01T05:49:57",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2020-08-01T05:49:57",
        "type": "variable",
        "status": "publish",
        "featured": false,
        "catalog_visibility": "visible",
        "description": "",
        "short_description": "",
        "sku": "",
        "price": "95",
        "regular_price": "",
        "sale_price": "",
        "date_on_sale_from": null,
        "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
        "date_on_sale_to": null,
        "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
        "price_html": "<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#8377;</span>95.00</span> &ndash; <span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#8377;</span>219.00</span>"};
        
        console.log(myObj['price_html']);
```